# Reliably determine if vector of floating point values is (numerically) equidistant

Tags: floating-point

Lets say one has a vector of floating point values.

```
X = [x1, x2, x3 ... xN]
```

I would like to check wether these values are equidistantly spaced. Of course, due to floating point arithmetic, one cannot guarantee that the adjacent differences are all the same.

What is a robust algorithm to perform this check?

Robust in the sense that it

- makes no assumption on the magnitude and sign of the vector elements
- nor on the length of the vector
- works whether the equidistant sequence was generate by repeated incrementing or by multiplication `i*dx + x0`.

Currently I look at the vector of differences, round them to a certain number of decimal places and then check if they are all the same. However this is not robust enough and sometimes fails if the vector is long.
The number of decimal places I choose is the `log10` of the maximum absolute vector value times `eps` times 10, i.e. `log10( max(abs(vec))*eps*10 )`

EDIT: This is the current code (in MATLAB) and the case that fails. Everything is `double`i.e. IEEE binary64 type

```
function [b, v0, dv] = isequidistant(vec)
    diffv = diff(vec);
    % Note round(x,N) rounds to the N-th decimal place, e.g. round(1234, -2) == 1200
    diffv = round( diffv, -ceil(log10(max(abs(vec(~isinf(vec)&vec ~= 0)))*eps*10)) );
    diffv = unique( diffv );
    if length(diffv) == 1
        b = true;
        v0 = vec(1);
        dv = diffv;
    else
        b = false;
        v0 = vec(1);
        dv = nan;
    end
end
```

This here fails:
`isequidistant( [0:330000]*3.027872455e-01 ) == 0`

Most interestingly
`isequidistant( [0:330000]*3.02787245e-01 ) == 1`

I know that one probably could play around with the constants and factors, but I am seeking a better solution here. That the above one generates a spurious failure actually worries me.

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs where your method fails (e.g., give an algorithm which generates such a sequence)? Repeated increments and `i*dx+x0` and `(x0*(N-i) + xN*i) / N` (and other alternatives) might generate sequences which can't be reproduced by either of the other methods. Do you assume IEEE 754 binary64/binary32 floats or anything (even with arbitrary bases?)

Comment: Re “The number of decimal places I choose is the log10 of the maximum absolute vector value times eps times 10”: What? So if 100 is the maximum absolute vector value, you have log10 is 2, epsilon is 2^-52 for IEEE-754 binary64, and 10, so 2•2^−52•10 = 4.44e-15 decimal places. That makes no sense. Try again?

Comment: What is the largest N you need? What bounds do you know for x0 and dx? Are they always non-negative? Any test that accepts points that would be equally spaced but for rounding errors in calculations must necessarily accept some points that are not equally spaced. How much tolerance do you have for such false positives? What would cause your points not to be equally spaced—do they arise from some process that would give us information about how much they must deviate from equal spacing?

Comment: Re “…and makes no assumption on how this equidistant sequence was generated”: That is an impossible condition to work with. In general, the compounding of arithmetic errors can produce errors that range from 0 to infinity or can be NaNs. You **must** have some  restrictions on how the numbers were produced, so that bounds on the potential errors can be established.

Comment: @chtz I added my (MATLAB) code and a test case that fails.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry, I should have written a formula. See my edit. The log10 is taken over everything (including the *eps*10)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I would be happy over a solution that is guarantueed to work for `i*dx+x0` and the repeated incrementing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree, the errors can be very large. but still there is determinism which should allow for solution of this problem. I hope :-). Lets exclude the pathological cases which generate Inf and NaN.

Comment: The criterion “nor on the length of the vector” is not useful; the length of the vector is necessarily known. Then we can compute a new vector [y1…yN] where yi = (xN-x1)/N•i + x1. This computation may have rounding errors, but bounds for them can be calculated. Then we can compare xi to yi and see whether the differences are within the bounds of sum of the yi errors and the errors permissible in the xi by either the increment or multiplication methods. If any is not, we know the points are not equally spaced. If they all are, we might accept it as a vector resulting from equally spaced points.

Comment: Note that, with the increment method, there may be errors in each of the N-1 increments, and each error has a bound proportional to the element, and this can produce an O(N^2) effect, so an error tolerance proportional to N would not be correct.

Comment: `max(abs(linspace(v(1),v(end),length(v))-v))` would be zero for both example vectors (you could compare it against `eps*max(abs(v(1)),abs(v(end)))`, if you want to accept some tolerance)

Comment: My previous comments neglect the error that might exist in xN as it is used to calculate the yi, which could be O(N^2). x1 could also have some error from the real point it originated from.

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward approach would be to generate a linear-spaced sequence between the first and last element and compare each element against that.

The code below allows comparing with some tolerance. The tolerance parameter could be made optional (default to `0` or `eps`, for example):

```
function [b, v0, dv] = isequidistant(vec, tolerance)
    v0 = vec(1); vN = vec(end); N = length(vec);
    b = all(abs(linspace(v0,vN,N)-vec) <= tolerance * max(abs(v0),abs(vN)));
    dv = (vN - v0) / (N-1);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As some degree of imprecision is allowed and still considered "equidistant", consider calculating all differences, record the highest and lowest, and then finally access the difference between hi and lo relative to the average.

```
// Pseudo code
X = [x1, x2, x3 ... xN]
if (N <= 2) return true;
avg = sum(x1...xN)/N
lo = x2 - x1
hi = x2 - x1
for (i = 3 to N)
   diff = xi - x(i-1)
   if (diff < lo) lo = diff
   if (diff > hi) hi = diff
 
 Now assess if lo,hi are too far apart
 Maybe by comparing the |(hi-lo)/avg| <= tolerance
```